# Unity 3d Player moves out of play area

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I have player,as shown in the image on a bridge.I want his movement to be restricted to the bridge.(at present he can run outside the bridge in air).How should i achive this.?

1 method i have thought of is to use use continous collision detection between the bridge and the player,to check if he stays within the area.is this the right way to approach?and are there any other alternate ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuous Collision Detection isn't strictly necessary unless it's moving really fast.

I see to way:

1. Use 3 collider: one for the player the other 2 for limit the sides of the bridge. This way the player can't compenetrate colliders and won't fall dawn.
2. Manually check inside input handling function that the limits of player movements (since the bridge has a simple shape, it shouldn't be difficult)

Comment: the 1st option ,the bridge's mesh is aon external obj i used and its parts are  not properly broken down b itself.can i do somthing manually(like have a transparent rectangle around the sides with colliders n it?) 3\2nd option actually theres apart of the pridge which isnt exactly straight so it wouldnt work out

Comment: @Kaushik Sivakumar: avoid MeshCollider whenever possible for performance reasons. Put two empty GameObject with BoxCollider on the sides of the bridge.

Comment: thanks actually  previous comment seems to be what wat looking for.another thing a bit unrelated collision detectio seems to take place only after sumtime?like when a player enters a bridge or leaves it .it recognises the change only after sometime,is that because of the perfomance issue you talked about?